# what does this mean in english?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic

I ran across a piece of code that says,

```
If (ProcessID <> 0) And ("O" <> sProcessStatus And "E" <> sProcessStatus) Then
    ' Do stuff
End If
```

What I don't understand is the 2nd condition... Can someone tell me if I am way off.

Does the 2nd condition say if `sProcessStatus` not O and E then do something?

Sanity check.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation. Anything else wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Side-note: use `AndAlso` instead of `And` in almost all cases. The former will evaluate the second condition only if the first evaluated to `true` whereas the latter will evaluate all conditions always. This is less efficient and can cause side effects. Consider this: `If str IsNot Nothing AndAlso str.ToLower="o"` will never throw an exception but `If str IsNot Nothing And str.ToLower="o"` does if `str` is `Nothing`. The same applies to `OrElse` and `Or`.

Comment: @Tim Why? If the first condition is false, why bother evaluating the rest?

Comment: @Andrew: You have misunderstood me or I did not express myself well. The `And` OP is using will evaluate all even if the first condition is false. That's not desired in most cases.

Comment: @Tim: Ah, then I must have misread it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that means it will only be true if all of the following conditions are true:

- `ProcessID` is anything other than zero
- `sProcess` is anything other than `"O"` or `"E"`

Gotta love *Yoda conditions*.  "O" it is not!  The force with "E" it is not...

Comment: Yoda conditions. I like it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One note though... because they are all ands... the parenthesis aren't necessary...

Answer (score 0):

if first condition not 0
AND
if second condition not "O" and not "E" then do something, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The second portion is saying if sProcessStatus is not O and sProcessStatus is not E then perform the action

In other words (this isn't correct syntax, just easier to read)

```
if spProcessSatus NOT IN ('O','E') {
 process
}
```